# How to transfer events into the canvas { pointer-events : none }; (!in KonvaJS)

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, pointer-events, konvajs

The essence of the title is described and presented in my [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jSerge/vfp22dye/).
My task is to make the pseudo shape. You need to hover on the canvas element (triangle), canvas accepted property `{pointer-events:all}`, and the care with this element `{pointer-events:none}`. How this can be done using the framework konvajs.

```js
    /*NON GIST*/
    var stage=new Konva.Stage({container:'container',width:300,height:300})
       ,layer=new Konva.Layer()
       ,triangle=new Konva.RegularPolygon({x:80,y:120,sides:3,radius:80,fill:'#00D2FF',stroke:'black',strokeWidth:4})
       ,text=new Konva.Text({x:10,y:10,fontFamily:'Calibri',fontSize:24,text:'',fill:'black'});
    function writeMessage(message){text.setText(message);layer.draw();}
    /*GIST*/
        triangle.on('mouseout', function() {

          $('#container').css('pointer-events',/*!*/'none');

          writeMessage('Mouseout triangle');
        });
        
        /*! How do I know if the events are not tracked on the canvas?*/
        triangle.on('mousemove', function() {

          $('#container').css('pointer-events',/*!*/'all');
          
          var mousePos = stage.getPointerPosition();
          var x = mousePos.x - 190;
          var y = mousePos.y - 40;
          writeMessage('x: ' + x + ', y: ' + y);
        });
    /*/GIST/*/
    layer.add(triangle);
    layer.add(text);
    stage.add(layer);
```

```css
    body{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #F0F0F0;}
    #container{
      position:absolute;
      z-index:1;
    }
    .lower-dom-element{
        position:absolute;
        z-index:0;
        padding:20px;
        background:#0e0;
        top: 90px;
        left: 0px;}
```

```html
     <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/0.9.0/konva.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <div id="container"></div>
    <div class="lower-dom-element">
        If the POINTER-EVENTS on me, then canvas POINTER-EVENTS:NONE, and vice versa.
        If the events are not on the triangle, then the event with me.
      </div>
```

PS: sorry for my english.

Comment: Maybe trigger the events on your desired element manually using jQuery? https://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: How do I know that the cursor is over the coordinates of the corresponding element of the canvas? If your theory works, then please give a link to an example.

Comment: KonvaJS will report the position of any of its elements relative to the canvas and you can get the position of the canvas relative to the viewport with `canvas.getBoundingClientRect`. Then by subscribing to mouse events on the document you can test if any of the events occurred over a KonvaJS object. Use jQuery's `.trigger` to transfer the browser-created mouse events to whichever element or KonvaJS object you want to receive that event. Or more directly, since you now know whichever element or KonvaJS object is the target of the event, just do the code you desire for that event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $con = $('#container');
$(document.body).mousemove(function(event) {
    var x = event.clientX, y = event.clientY;
    var offset = $con.offset();
    // manually check intersection
    if (layer.getIntersection({x: x - offset.left, y: y - offset.top})){        
        $con.css('pointer-events',/*!*/'all');
    } else {
        $con.css('pointer-events',/*!*/'none');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vfp22dye/3/